# ip addressing for Nth computers

Tags: ip, addressing

the question is, calculate these information:

"ip subnet zero, first ip, last ip, broadcast, ip subnet mask"

for a Class B IP (172.16.0.0/16) for X number of PCs, for example, for 27811 computers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Address:   172.16.0.0            10101100.00010000 .00000000.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.0.0 = 16      11111111.11111111 .00000000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.255.255           00000000.00000000 .11111111.11111111
=>
Network:   172.16.0.0/16         10101100.00010000 .00000000.00000000 (Class B)
Broadcast: 172.16.255.255        10101100.00010000 .11111111.11111111
HostMin:   172.16.0.1            10101100.00010000 .00000000.00000001
HostMax:   172.16.108.163        10101100.00010000 .11111111.11111110
Hosts/Net: 27811 (Private Internet)
```

For a Class B IP address the first 16 digits should be static(they will never change). The remaining 16 digits keep changing...

So for ur problem.. the IP addresses go like this...

```
172.16.0.1 ..... 172.16.0.255
172.16.1.0 ..... 172.16.1.255
.
.
.
172.16.107.0 ..... 172.16.107.255
172.16.108.0 ..... 172.16.108.163 ---> This will count to 27811 hosts
```

Comment: is this for 65534 hosts?!? if so, how can I calculate those information for 27811 hosts?!

Comment: For 27811 .. you have to split 3rd field into 256 chunks. Calculate it for 27811/256. That number should work..

Comment: Your Hostmax would be 172.16.108.163